# VBA Protect Function Applies the Wrong Password

Tags: excel, vba

I start the Workbook_Open event with this line of code

```
Table1.Protect Password = "Secret", UserInterFaceOnly:=True
```

However, when I try to unlock it with

```
Table1.Unprotect ("Secret")
```

it does not work.

The Password Cracker says, that a working password would be "AAAAAAAABABF"

How do I actually set "Secret" as the password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR** Read the article that Rory wrote (in his answer below)

Firstly, your protect code is wrong (missing a colon `:`):

```
Table1.Protect Password = "Secret", UserInterFaceOnly:=True
```

This is assigning `Password` which will be treated as an undeclared variable (did you forget to use `Option Explicit`?)

It should be this:

```
Table1.Protect Password:= "Secret", UserInterFaceOnly:=True
```

---

> The Password Cracker says, that a working password would be "AAAAAAAABABF"

This is because these kinds of passwords in Excel are not secure (this is well documented). Passwords of this nature in Excel rely on more of a numerical value where each character is assigned a numeric value... so:

```
d = 4
a = 1

(a + a + a + a) = d
```

and so in this case using `d` or `aaaa` would work as your password. (This is a crude example of how it works, not the exact methods).

Comment: Working now! Will Accept this answer in 5 Minutes

Comment: @Tom That's true of workbook protection, for sheet protection it's still very easily broken.

Comment: @Tom Unzipping the file and using a hex editor works nicely. Google will throw up a few tutorials for you.

Comment: @MacroMan - Cheers will have to have a look

Answer (score 5):

It's a common mistake (so common I wrote this: http://excelmatters.com/2013/10/03/whats-in-a-colon/).

Your `Protect` code is missing a colon:

```
Table1.Protect Password:="Secret", UserInterFaceOnly:=True
```

You were actually protecting the workbook with the password False, since that's the result of the expression:

```
Password = "Secret"
```